# Кто и зачем

Tags: словообразование

почему,жи-ши пишутся через и? и кто придумал это правило?

Answer (score 2):

ОТВЕТ, КОТОРЫЙ БОЛЬШЕ ПОХОЖ НА ВОПРОС

Тема правописания  ЖИ-ШИ (а также ЧА-ЩА, ЧУ-ЩУ) возникает на форумах постоянно - видно, удовлетворительный ответ пока не получен.

Казалось бы ясно: написание ЖИ-ШИ отражает древнерусское произношение, когда шипящие  звуки Ж и Ш были мягкими. В 13 веке произошло их отвердение, и слова, содержащие эти звуки, стали произноситься твёрдо, но их написание  сохранилось прежним. Только  почему оно сохранилось прежним - вот в чем вопрос. Для сравнения для буквы Ц мы же имеем другую картину.

Звук Ц в древнерусском языке также был мягким, его отвердение началось в 14-15 веках  и к 17 веку отразилось на письме: отцы, улицы, бледнолицый, лисицын, а также цыган, цыпленок, на цыпочках.(Кажется, написание И в таких словах, как циновка, цирюльник, цифра, панцирь, было установлено только Правилами 1956 года?).

Для ЧА-ЩА, ЧУ-ЩУ также картина неясная, эти-то звуки всегда были мягкими. И на эту тему не получается найти убедительной информации.